# Find a Series of Rows That Maximizes a Condition

Tags: r

I want to find a series of consecutive rows in a dataset where a condition is met the most often.

I have two columns that I can use for this; Either one with ones and zeros that alternate based on the presence or absence of a condition or a column which increments for the duration across which the desirable condition is present. I envision that I will need to use [subset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022511/how-to-subset-a-list-based-on-the-length-of-its-elements-in-r),[filter()](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/filter.html), and/or [rle()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875716/find-start-and-end-positions-indices-of-runs-consecutive-values) in order to make this happen but am at a loss as to how to get it to work.

In the example, I want to find 6 sequential rows that maximize the instances in which `happens` occurs.

Given the input:

```
library(data.frame)
df<-data.frame(time=c(1:10),happens=c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1),count=c(1,2,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2))
```

I would like to see as the output the rows 5 through 10, inclusive, as the data subset output, using either the `happens` or `count` columns since this sequence of rows would yield the highest output of `happens` occurrences on 6 consecutive rows.

Comment: Is 6 part of your input or how should this be detected?

Comment: Although Wimpel answered this, as a courtesy I thought I should answer your question. 6 would be a fixed value that is known in advance and could be used as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(zoo)
which.max( rollapply( df$happens, 6, sum) )
#[1] 5
```

The fifth window of 6 rows apparently holds the maximum sum of df$happens
So the answer is row 5:10

Comment: That's the one. I spent two days trying to figure this out. I really appreciate this. Thanks.